# Flutter: StateError was thrown building: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I was making a travel app and I came through this. So I am trying to display an image from Firebase Cloud Storage whose link is stored in Firebase Firestore. While all the images in the storage are being displayed I'm still getting this error. [Error show on the emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqdGh.png).

My code that I am trying to run:

```
    class DestinationGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('destinations')
            .orderBy('name')
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("error");
          }
          if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            final destination = querySnapshot.data.docs;
            return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              itemCount: destination.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(destination[index]['name']),
                    ),
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                      child: Image.network(
                        destination[index]['imageUrl'],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```